# AWS S3 endpoint issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-filesystem, illuminate

This is a really strange one as it started throwing errors over night - it's been working fine up until yesterday - this morning it's been playing all day.

I'm using `illuminate/filesystem` in my project and for the endpoint I was using:

```
https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

This morning we started getting errors saying:

> Error executing "ListObjects" on "bucket-01.https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 1: Protocol "bucket-01.https" not supported or disabled in libcurl (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
> File: .../vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php
> Line: 195

Seeing that it tries to prepend bucket name before the protocol of the endpoint I've decided to remove protocol from the endpoint - making it

```
s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Now I'm getting error saying

> Error executing "ListObjects" on "//bucket-01.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-01.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com";
> AWS HTTP error: Client error: `GET http://bucket-01.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-01.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response
> NoSuchKey The specified key does not exist.

As you can see now it appends endpoint after the initial endpoint.
Does anyone know what might have happened?

Comment: Is it always the same bucket? Did you install any updates?

Comment: It is always the same bucket and I didn't install any updates recently.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching for the solution I've came across this issue on laravel/framework repository https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/36694